# How to use dynamic months in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field called End Reminder Date and I want to calculate the next Reminder Date by adding  21 days for the current selected Reminder Date .  I am using a variable to capture what month the user is selecting then I want to calculate the next month reminder date, so for example:
User selects either Nov, Dec or Jan, this is what I would like to see in my select statement:
[image]

this is what i started but it is not dynamic

```
Declare @Nov int
set @Nov = 11
select End_Reminder_Date,
case when @Nov like '%11%' then End_Reminder_Date +21 end as Next_Month_Reminder
 from myTable
```

Comment: Link to docs for answers below: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: how is 10/23/2015 +21= 12/25/2015 ?  are we talking calendar days or business days? what?

Comment: @xQbert..i think it is a 21 day difference column-wise. bad formatting i guess

Comment: I get it November = 1*21+10/23/2015 dec = 2*21+10/23/2015 and jan = 3*21 + 10/23/2015..gotcha.

Comment: How is the value of the user selects assigned?  if it can be an offset from current month then the math in comment above should work fine. 
`select dateadd(day,21*P_Offset_I, P_End_Reminder_Date_I) as Next_Month_Reminder`

Comment: user select the month name from drop down box so based on the month selection then i want to calculate next month reminder.  please show me how this work.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `End_Reminder_Date` is a Date or DateTime column (or variable).

Then just use `DATEADD`

```
Declare @End_Reminder_Date DateTime

Select @End_Reminder_Date = '11/23/2015'

Select DateAdd (Day, 21, @End_Reminder_Date) Next_Month_Reminder
```

Comment: Raj, this is good but what about if i want to give them the option to select only the Month instead of the date?  I want them to select like December or January etc how do i change this? Select @End_Reminder_Date = '12/4/2015'

Comment: What happens when they just select a month? What day of the month would be your starting point?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEADD`.

```
select dateadd(dd, 21, End_Reminder_Date) as Next_Month_Reminder
from myTable
```